# How to simplify the error handling in tamejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, tamejs

I'm pretty happy with tamejs, it makes my javascript code much clearer. But I still feel the error handling is a little boring.

See the code:

```
// callback should be callback(err, nextInt)
function inc(n, callback) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      callback(null, n+1);
   }, 100);
}

await { inc(3, defer(var err, next));}
if(err) throw new Error(err);          // !!! error handling

await { inc(8, defer(var err, next));}
if(err) throw new Error(err);          // !!! error handling

await { inc(12, defer(var err, next));}
if(err) throw new Error(err);          // !!! error handling

await { inc(39, defer(var err, next));}
if(err) throw new Error(err);          // !!! error handling
```

Since nearly every asynchronous api has callbacks which have a `error` as the first parameter, we need to get it and check it first.

You can see there are a lot of error handling lines in the sample, which is boring.

Is there any way to simplify it?

Comment: Fyi, you do not need `{}` around a single-statement `await` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
function asyncCheck(workFunction) {
  await { workFunction(defer(var err, next)) };
  if (err) throw new Error(err);
}

//Then use closures to define the work

asyncCheck(function (callback) { inc(2, callback}));
```

I haven't tried tamejs myself, just read about it, but perhaps this pattern will work?

Comment: Thanks, this is an option, but not help much.